# Attempting To Make A Color Picker Command

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to make a color picker command in discord python that allows people to pick a custom color using a hex code. It does this by creating a role named the author of the message, and then setting the color of the role to the hex code that was sent in chat with the command db!color (Hex Code). But for some reason I get the error

```py
SyntaxError: invalid hexadecimal literal
```

Here Is The Code

```py
elif message.content.startswith('db!color'):
        role = str(message.author)
        color = message.content.replace('db!color ', '')
        guild = message.author.guild
        sleep(0.3)
        print(color)
        if get(message.guild.roles, name=role):
            await role.edit(guild=message.guild, role=role, color=discord.Color(0x + int(color))
        else:
            await guild.create_role(role=role, color=discord.Color(0x + int(color))
```

Comment: The SyntaxError comes probably from the last line: `cord.Color(0x + int(color))` where `0x` is not a valid "hexadecimal literal. I guess you want to put quote around: `"0x" + str(color)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use `discord.Color()` function that much but I think what you can use is:

```py
if get(message.guild.roles, name=role):
    await role.edit(guild=message.guild color=int(color, 16))
else:
    await guild.create_role(color=int(color, 16))
```

Note that the only valid for this command syntax is something like: `db!color FF000`. If the user enter something like `db!color #FF0000` as the color you have to remove the "#" from the string.

Comment: What does the 16 do in color=int(color, 16). trying to understand what im putting in my code.

Comment: This Code returns the error
```py
  File "\\DESKTOP-H1GG905\He\bot.py", line 158, in on_message
    await guild.create_role(role=role, color=int(color,16))
  File "C:\Users\Mikey Reeves\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1788, in create_role
    raise InvalidArgument('%r is not a valid field.' % key)
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: 'role' is not a valid field.```

Comment: The `int(color, 16)` coverts the string variable "color" from hex to base 10.

Comment: From your error it's saying that the role key word is not a field, so I think you have to remove the `role=role` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use an `on_message` events, However I have created this example using a command which makes this task a lot easier, instead of having to filter more specific results using an event.

With this command, you can use Eg `db!color red` which would create a red colour role, or instead you can also use the hexadecimal code too, `#ff0000`. `discord.Color` can be passed as a parameter to allow this, then your `color` variable stores the user's color input.

```py
@client.command()
async def color(ctx, colour: discord.Colour):
    name = ctx.author.name
    await ctx.send('Created role with colour: ' + str(colour))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name=name, colour=colour)
```